# How to include programmatically in ng-content some components filtered by specific tagname in angular?

Tags: angular, ng-content

I would like to simplify developper experience in my angular library.
That´s why I´m trying to use a ng-content with a specific select which be automaticaly populated without the developper needs to add the class.

Example:

## Application

### app.component.html

```
<lib-frame-component>
   <lib-panel-component [modal]="true"></lib-panel-component>
</lib-frame-component>
```

## Library

### lib-frame-component.html

```
 <!-- developper should not need to use class="modals-content" to include lib-panel-component(s) -->
 <ng-content select='.modals-content'></ng-content>
```

### lib-frame-component.ts

```
// get lib-panel-components inserted by the developper
@ContentChildren( LibPanelComponent, { descendants: false } ) directPanels: QueryList<PanelComponent>;
...
// Do something like that somewhere in the life cycle...
this.directPanels.forEach(( panelComponent: LibPanelComponent) => {
  if ( panelComponent.modal === true ) {
     // TODO : code to insert in ng-content.modals-content
  }
}
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/guide/content-projection

Try to look throught the official docs.

If you do not use select on ng-content it would take content that will not be populated in ng-content's with select, by default.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot programmatically change the projected content inside `ng-content` because it is not meant to work this way. If you want to narrow down what is shown, you need to come up with a more specific selector, e.g:

```html
<ng-content select="lib-panel-component[shown]"></ng-content>
```

Then, whoever is using your library can specify what needs to be shown like this:

```html
<lib-frame-component>
 <!-- this will be projected -->
 <lib-panel-component [modal]="true" shown></lib-panel-component>

 <!-- this will not be projected -->
 <lib-panel-component></lib-panel-component>
</lib-frame-component>
```

Or, if you insist on programmatically changing stuff on the projected content (not advised), you can add an `@Input` property to the `LibPanelComponent` which then you can change inside `lib-frame-component.ts`:

```js
this.directPanels.forEach(( panelComponent: LibPanelComponent) => {
  if ( panelComponent.modal === true ) {
     panelComponent.hidePanelContent = true;
  }
}
```

And then, you'd need to wrap the component markup of `LibPanelComponent` in a container with an `*ngIf`, for example:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="!hidePanelContent">
<!-- LibPanelComponent markup -->
</div>
```

The second approach will leave you with a bunch of empty `<lib-panel-component></lib-panel-component>` components in the DOM.